# YAML CF template for Cloud formation security group with multiple CIDR IPs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am creating cloudformation template in YAML for security group with the below aim.

If I input 3 CIDR IPs(59.188.255.128/26,34.224.81.192/26,35.223.13.224/27) in parameter (IPs), security group should be created with ingress 3 CIDR IPs.
If I input 2 CIDR IPs(59.188.255.128/26,34.224.81.192/26) in parameter (IPs), security group should be created with those ingress 2 CIDR IPs.
If I input 1 CIDR IP(59.188.255.128/26) in parameter (IPs), security group should be created with that ingress 1 CIDR IPs.

I am getting error while validating my template in Cloudformation designer.

```
Template contains errors.: Template format error: YAML not well-formed. (line 17, column 28)
```

Is the below template fulfil the purpose?
Also I am unable to detect the error. Can someone help me on this.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Security Group for CIDR IPs
Parameters:
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id
    Description: VPC where the Security Group will belong
  Name:
    Type: String
    Description: Name Tag of the Security Group
  Description:
    Type: String
    Description: Description Tag of the Security Group
  IPs:
    Description: Comma-delimited list of three CIDR IPs
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
Conditions:
  IsIPthereA: !Not [!Equals["",!Select [ 0, !Ref IPs ] ]]
  IsIPthereB: !Not [!Equals["",!Select [ 1, !Ref IPs ] ]]
  IsIPthereC: !Not [!Equals["",!Select [ 2, !Ref IPs ] ]]
Resources:
  MYSG:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: !Ref Description
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          CidrIp: !If [IsIPthereA, !Select [ 0, !Ref IPs ], !Ref AWS::NoValue]
          FromPort: 443
          ToPort: 443
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          CidrIp: !If [IsIPthereB, !Select [ 1, !Ref IPs ], !Ref AWS::NoValue]
          FromPort: 443
          ToPort: 443
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          CidrIp: !If [IsIPthereC, !Select [ 2, !Ref IPs ], !Ref AWS::NoValue]
          FromPort: 443
          ToPort: 443
Outputs:
  SecurityGroupID:
    Description: Security Group ID
    Value: !Ref MYSG
```

**Update:**
Invalidation error got fixed. Now, there is no issue in creating stack with 3 CIDR IPs as parameter. But while creating stack with 2 CIDR IPs as parameter inputs(54.183.255.128/26,34.223.80.192/26), I am getting "Template error: Fn::Select cannot select nonexistent value at index 2". Can someone please help on fixing this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Validation Error is because there is no space after !Equals.

even if you fix the space issue, it will fail when the IPs array doesn't have length 3 because of !Select function cannot select from an index that doesn't exist.

in order to make it work, Join your list with empty strings list then validate.

```
Conditions:
  IsIPthereA: 
    Fn::Not: 
      - Fn::Equals:
        - Fn::Select:
          - 0
          - Fn::Split:
            - ","
            - Fn::Sub:
              - "${IP},,,"
              - IP: !Join [',', !Ref IPs] 
        - ""
  IsIPthereB: 
    Fn::Not: 
      - Fn::Equals:
        - Fn::Select:
          - 1
          - Fn::Split:
            - ","
            - Fn::Sub:
              - "${IP},,,"
              - IP: !Join [',', !Ref IPs] 
        - ""
  IsIPthereC: 
    Fn::Not: 
      - Fn::Equals:
        - Fn::Select:
          - 2
          - Fn::Split:
            - ","
            - Fn::Sub:
              - "${IP},,,"
              - IP: !Join [',', !Ref IPs] 
        - ""
```

Comment: Thanks @Shiyas. Now stack validation completed.  There is no issue in creating stack with 3 CIDR IPs as parameter.  But while creating stack with 2 CIDR IPs  as parameter inputs(54.183.255.128/26,34.223.80.192/26), I am getting "Template error: Fn::Select cannot select nonexistent value at index 2".  Could you please help on fixing this error.

Comment: I've updated the answer, Split cannot lookup into non index value.

Comment: Thanks @Shiya. I will test the stack and revert back.

Comment: any update on this... ?

Comment: Thanks @Shiyas. Its working.  I am accepting you answer as solved.